# Problem in solving a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation $:$

$$4yp^2 + 2xp - y = 4,\ \text {where}\ p = \frac {dy} {dx}.$$

I tried to transform the above equation in Clairaut's form but I am unable to do so. I first expressed $y$ in terms of $x$ and $p$ as follows $:$ $$y = \frac {4 - 2xp} {4p^2 - 1}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)$$ Now differentiating both sides of $(1)$ w.r.t. $x$ and simplifying I get $$(8xp^2 + 2x - 32 p) \frac {dp} {dx} = 16 p^5 - p.$$ which is not in any suitable form as far as I know. So at this stage I got stuck and couldn't proceed further. Can anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I finally find is that $$x = \frac {32 (p^2 - 4)} {p^2} \int \frac {p^2} {(4-p^2) (16p^4 - 1)}\ dp + \frac {C(4-p^2)} {p^2}$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: @Moo you are right. If I solve it for $x$ the thing become easier. By doing that I get $$y = \frac {1} {p}\  \ln \left [ \left (4 + \frac {1} {p^2} \right )^2 \right ]+ \frac {C} {p}$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: @Moo I think that now I have to substitute the value of $y$ in the original equation to get an expression for $x$ in terms of $p.$ Then $x$ and $y$ as functions of $p$ together give the general solution of the given differential equation. Am I right?